# How to disable previous days from datepicker "TO" after I`ve chosen "FROM" date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker and when I select the "FROM" date, it should automatically disable in the "FROM" datepicker all the dates that are before the selected one. Any help please ?

Comment: could you please set up a fiddle with what you have got already?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kZBEt/   right now, I found this solution but it has a bug. If you select the end date first, you will be able to setup future dates or pretty much anything in the START date. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/kZBEt/447/ ?

Comment: Thank you!!! This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kZBEt/447/

```
startDate:<div class="datepickerFrom"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
end Date:<div class="datepickerTill"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".datepickerFrom" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: "#dateFrom",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var date2 = $(".datepickerFrom").datepicker("getDate");
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
        $(".datepickerTill").datepicker("setDate", date2);
        $(".datepickerTill").datepicker("option", "minDate", date2);
    }
});
$( ".datepickerTill" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: "#dateTill",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: 1
});
$("#dateFrom").change(function(){
    $(".datePickerTill").datepicker("setDate", $(this).val());
});
</script>
```